# Find channel name of message with SlackClient

Tags: python, python-2.7, slack-api, slack

I am trying to print the channel a message was posted to in slack with the python SlackClient. After running this code I only get an ID and not the channel name.

```
import time
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient

BOT_TOKEN = os.environ.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN')

def main():
    # Creates a slackclient instance with bots token
    sc = SlackClient(BOT_TOKEN)

    #Connect to slack
    if sc.rtm_connect():
        print "connected" 
        while True:
            # Read latest messages
            for slack_message in sc.rtm_read():
                message = slack_message.get("text")
                print message
                channel = slack_message.get("channel")
                print channels
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output:

```
test
U1K78788H
```

Comment: Maybe this? https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.info  Or maybe call this once and store the results in a `dict`? https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list

Answer (score 2):

This will always produce a channel id and not channel name. You must call **channels.info** to get the channel name.

```
import time
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient

BOT_TOKEN = os.environ.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN')

def main():
# Creates a slackclient instance with bots token
sc = SlackClient(BOT_TOKEN)

#Connect to slack
if sc.rtm_connect():
    print "connected" 
    while True:
        # Read latest messages
        for slack_message in sc.rtm_read():
            message = slack_message.get("text")
            print message
            channel = slack_message.get("channel")
            print channel
            channel_info=sc.api_call("channels.info",channel=channel)
            print channel_info["channel"]["name"]
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will also print channel Name.
Another way is that you can store names of all the channels with their channel_id in a dictionary beforehand. And then get the channel name with id as key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are outputting. Shouldn't "channels" be "channel" ? Also, I think this output is the "user" field. The "Channel" field should yield an id starting with C or G ([doc](https://api.slack.com/events/message)).

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "channel": "C2147483705",
    "user": "U2147483697",
    "text": "Hello world",
    "ts": "1355517523.000005"
}
```

Then, use either the python client to retrieve the channel name, if it stores it (I don't know the Python client), or use the web API method [channels.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.info) to retrieve the channel name.